# Long polling in Yesod

Tags: haskell, long-polling, yesod, haskell-snap-framework, happstack

Can I do long polling in Yesod, or any other Haskell web framework with comparable database facilities?

To be precise, I want to delay a HTTP response until something interesting happens. There should also be a timeout after which the client will be served a response saying "nothing happened" and then the client will issue the same request.

To make life even more complicated, the app I have in mind is serving all its stuff over both HTTP/HTML5 and a really compact UDP protocol to MIDP clients. Events from either protocol can release responses in either protocol.

TIA,
Adrian.

Answer (score 7):

I can't answer all the issues of the more complicated UDP stuff, but the short answer is that, yes, Yesod supports long polling. You can essentially do something like:

```
myHandler = do
    mres <- timeout timeoutInMicroseconds someAction
    case mres of
        Nothing -> return nothingHappenedResponse
        Just res -> doSomething res
```

You'll probably want to used System.Timeout.Lifted from the lifted-base package.

Comment: Would this procedure exhaust threads on the server if faced with lots of requests? I came here after following the discussion of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405950/what-is-a-restful-way-of-monitoring-a-rest-resource-for-changes

Comment: GHC's runtime supports a very large number of green threads. I highly doubt that the number of threads will end up being the limiting factor on resources.

Answer (score 4):

Michael's answer hits the timeout requirement. For general clients you do not want to keep HTTP responses waiting for more than about 60 seconds as they may be connecting through a proxy or similar which tend to get impatient after about that long. If you're on a more tightly controlled network then you may be able to relax this timeout. One minor correction is that the parameter to `timeout` is in microseconds not nanoseconds.

For the 'wait for something interesting to happen' part, we use the `check` combinator from `Control.Concurrent.STM` (which wraps up `retry`) so our handler thread waits on a `TVar`:

```
someAction = do
    interestingStuff <- atomically $ do
        currentStuff <- readTVar theStuff
        check $ isInteresting currentStuff
        return currentStuff
    respondWith interestingStuff
```

Meanwhile, other threads (incl HTTP handlers) are updating `theStuff :: TVar Stuff` - each update triggers a new calculation of `isInteresting` and potentially a response if it returns `True`.

This is compatible with serving the same information over UDP: simply share `theStuff` between your UDP server threads and the Yesod threads.